# Could indicator function be introduced into probability?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, conditional-probability

Suppose there are 3 random variables: $A_t\in\{0,1\},B_t,\text{and}\; B_{t-1}$. I would like to write a joint probability distribution to express the idea:

At time step $t$, $B_{t-1}=b$ has been observed. We sample $A_t$ from $P(A_t)$ first, if $A_t=1$ then we sample $B_t$ from $P(B_t|A_t=1)$; If $A_t=0$, then let $B_t=B_{t-1}=b$.

$$P(A_t,B_t|B_{t-1}=b)= P(A_t)P(B_t|A_t)\mathbb{1}[B_t=B_{t-1}]^{A_t}$$

Is this a valid distribution? What is a formal way to express the above idea? I checked this post [Conditional probability and indicator function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244368/conditional-probability-and-indicator-function/2244486#2244486) but did not come up with an formulation.

Comment: Sounds like you want to write $P(A_t=1,B_t \in C \mid B_{t-1}=b)=P(B_t \in C \mid A_t=1,B_{t-1}=b) P(A_t=1 \mid B_{t-1}=b)$.

Comment: @Ian Tks for your comment. Sorry I still have 2 questions: 1. how is the idea of $=−1= $ conveyed?  2. How to write $P(A_t=0)$?

Comment: The other case would be that $P(B_t=b,A_t=0)=P(B_t=b \mid A_t=0) P(A_t=0)$.